# determinant of crossing product of two matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ is the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices over $F$, and $B$ is a fixed $n\times n$ matrix over $F$. Let $L_B$ and $R_B$ be the linear operators on $V$ defined by $L_B(A) = BA$ and $R_B(A) = AB$ show that:

a) $\det(L_B) = (\det(B))^n$

b) $\det(R_B) = (\det(B))^n$

I was wondering if I should use the representation matrix of the operators or something else. Is there any formula for cross product of two matrices?

please help me on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
\begin{align}
\beta
&=\{E^{ij}\in V:1\le i,j\le n\}\\
&=\{E^{11},E^{21},\ldots,E^{n1},E^{12},E^{22},\ldots,E^{n2},\ldots,E^{1n},E^{2n},\ldots,E^{nn}\}
\end{align}
be the standard ordered basis
for $V$, where $E^{ij}$ is the matrix whose $ij$-entry is one and other
entries are zero. Observe that
\begin{align}
L_B(E^{ij})=BE^{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^nB_{ki}E^{kj},
\end{align}
where $B_{ki}$ denotes the $ki$-entry of $B$. Then the
matrix representation of $L_B$ with respect to $\beta$,
denoting $[L_B]_\beta$, is of the form
\begin{align}
[L_B]_\beta
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
B_{11}&B_{12}&\cdots&B_{1n}\\
B_{21}&B_{22}&\cdots&B_{2n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
B_{n1}&B_{n2}&\cdots&B_{nn}\\
&&&&B_{11}&B_{12}&\cdots&B_{1n}\\
&&&&B_{21}&B_{22}&\cdots&B_{2n}\\
&&&&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
&&&&B_{n1}&B_{n2}&\cdots&B_{nn}\\
&&&&&&&&\ddots\\
&&&&&&&&&B_{11}&B_{12}&\cdots&B_{1n}\\
&&&&&&&&&B_{21}&B_{22}&\cdots&B_{2n}\\
&&&&&&&&&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
&&&&&&&&&B_{n1}&B_{n2}&\cdots&B_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
B&&&\\
&B&&\\
&&\ddots&\\
&&&B
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
That is, $[L_B]_\beta$ is the diagonal block matrix consisting of 
$n$ times $B$. Finally, because the determinant of a linear operator
is independent of the choice of an ordered basis for $V$, we conclude that
$$\det(L_B)=\det([L_B]_\beta)=[\det(B)]^n,$$
where the second equality follows by **Appendix**. This completes 
the proof of (a), and the proof of (b) is similar.

---

**Appendix.**

We show that given a $k$-block matrix
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}B_1&&&\\&B_2&&\\&&\ddots&\\&&&&B_k\end{pmatrix},$$
where $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_k$ are square matrices (arbitrary size). Then
$$\det(M)=\det(B_1)\cdot\det(B_2)\cdots\det(B_k).$$
However, if we show the case of an $n\times n$ two-block matrix
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}A&\\&B\end{pmatrix},$$
then it can be easily extended to $k$-block matrix inductively. Fix
$B$ be $m\times m$, we use induction on $n$. Begin with $n=m+1$, then
$A=(A_{11})$ and it is clear that
$$\det(M)=A_{11}\cdot\det(B)=\det(A)\cdot\det(B).$$
Suppose that the result holds for some $n=m+l$, where $l\ge 1$. Then for
$n=m+(l+1)$, we apply the *cofactor* of the $ij$-entry of $A$, defined by
$$(-1)^{i+j}\cdot\det(\tilde{A}_{ij}),$$
where $\tilde{A}_{ij}$ is the $l\times l$ matrix obtained from $A$ by
deleting row $i$ and column $j$. Then
\begin{align}
\det(M)
&=\sum_{j=1}^{l+1}(-1)^{1+j}\cdot A_{1j}\cdot\det(\tilde{M}_{1j})\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{l+1}(-1)^{1+j}\cdot A_{1j}\cdot\det(\tilde{A}_{1j})\cdot\det(B)\tag{1}\\
&=\det(A)\cdot\det(B)\tag{2},
\end{align}
where $(1)$ follows by the assumption and $(2)$ follows by the definition of
$\det(A)$.